# Set a $_file variable in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to verifie if an image has a valid format with ajax. But I have a problem, how do I set a $_file variable in jQuery?

So I want to "translate" this php code:

```
        $Avatar = $_FILES['Avatar']['name'];
        $AvatarTmp = $_FILES['Avatar']['tmp_name'];
```

To jquery.

And here is (the important part of) the Php script that will be call ($.post):

```
            if(!empty($AvatarTmp))
        {
            $AvatarSize = getimagesize($AvatarTmp);

            if($AvatarSize['mime'] =='image/jpeg')
            {
                $AvatarSrc = imagecreatefromjpeg($AvatarTmp);                       
            }else

            if($AvatarSize['mime'] =='image/png')
            {   
                $AvatarSrc = imagecreatefrompng($AvatarTmp);                        
            }else

            if($AvatarSize['mime'] =='image/gif')
            {                       
                $AvatarSrc = imagecreatefromgif($AvatarTmp);
            }else
            {
                $Errors[] = "Error006";
                $AvatarSrc = false;
            }
        }
```

PS: if more code or anything is needed, ask, I'll add it right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately jQuery (JavaScript) is a wholly different beast from PHP, and so it doesn't have a File object of any type. As @VIPINJAIN mentioned there is the HTML5 file API coming, but it is in its infancy.

You're much better off checking by file extensions (see [Check input file for correct format with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846335/check-input-file-for-correct-format-with-jquery)) or doing the check server-side and outputting an error back from the server if it's in the wrong format.

== EDIT ==

Here is an example of how to use File API, including how to check file type with it, but bear in mind that this will only work in a [limited number of browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=file%20api):

http://robertnyman.com/2010/12/16/utilizing-the-html5-file-api-to-choose-upload-preview-and-see-progress-for-multiple-files/#highlighter_81142

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot send file in ajax request until and unless you are using html5 file api in mozilla firefox.

alternatively you can do this,

submit the form with file input to an iframe and on the load of the iframe get the contents of body element of iframe using jquery. and check the response of the server.

Comment: The reference to Firefox is misleading, it makes it look like it is the only browser with HTML5 File API support or will be